# Dropdownlist selects always the first item regardless of selected property (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use a dropdownlist, the problem is that the selected item is always the first item added. And the selected property set in the controller is completly ignored.

Maybe I'm missing something basic but I'm not seeing nothing wrong in the code.

Ho wever I can see that the generated HTML Code does not display the selected property either.

Do you guys find anything wrong in the code below?

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            HomeModel model = new HomeModel();
            List<SelectListItem> ddlItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            SelectListItem Opt1 = new SelectListItem { Text = "Opt1", Value = "1" };
            SelectListItem Opt2 = new SelectListItem { Text = "Opt2", Value = "2", Selected = true };
            ddlItems.Add(Opt1);//The first item added is always the selected one
            ddlItems.Add(Opt2);
            model.DDL = ddlItems;
            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

Model

```
  public class HomeModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> DDL { get; set; }

    }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DDL, Model.DDL, new { id = "ddlId"})
```

Generated HTML

```
 <select name="DDL" id="DDL">
    <option value="1">Opt1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt2</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (in your case `List<SelectListItem>`). Your model needs a property

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> DDL { get; set; }
}
```

and your method would be

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    HomeModel model = new HomeModel()
    {
       SelectedItem = 2, // set the default selection
       DDL = new List<SelectListItem>
       {
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Opt1", Value = "1" },
           new SelectListItem { Text = "Opt2", Value = "2" }
       }
    };
    return View(model); // no need for the view name
}
```

Note that there is no point setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` when you binding to a model (it's the value of the property that determines what is selected)

Then your view will be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem, Model.DDL)
```

Comment: Hello Stephen Muecke, this indeed works! but I would rather prefer to not use the SelectedItem property as it is less intuitive to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _less intuitive_? Its the way `DropDownListFor()` works - the first parameter is the value of the property your binding to and the second parameter is the collection used to generate the options.

Comment: less intuitive because you are binding to the selectedItem property instead of binding the model collection. It would be easier to understand with the selected property. but if i understood well, I can only achieve that with Dropdownlist (without binding), right?

Comment: But you cannot bind to a `<select>` to a collection (or indeed any html element) - that would make no sense at all. A `<select>` is for selecting one item in a collection, not for selecting the whole collection. And like all html controls, it only posts back one value, not a collection of values representing every property in the collection. And you cannot do it with `DropDownList()` either. When the form is submitted it will post back either `1` or `2`, neither of which can be bound to property `DDL` because its `List<SelectListItem>`, not `int`